# Is it possible to connect a DeploymentScript to a VNET?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

When running a bicep resource of type `Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts`
that runs a script that needs access to a keyvault which only allows selected networks how can we make the following script work?

[image]

```
resource exampleScript 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'KeyVaultSecretFromProduct'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/${managedIdentity.scope}/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/${managedIdentity.name}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    arguments: '-ResourceGroupName \\"${keyVaultSecretFromProduct.scope}\\" -SubscriptionKey \\"${subscriptionKey}\\" -KeyVault \\"${keyVaultSecretFromProduct.keyVault}\\"'
    azPowerShellVersion: '3.0'
    scriptContent: loadTextContent('../../membership-optimization/create-secret-for-product-key.ps1')
    retentionInterval: 'P1D'
  }
}
```

After running it fails with the error:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 15:37:50 - The deployment 'test_keyvault' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
Status Message: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details. (Code: DeploymentFailed)
 - {
  "status": "failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "DeploymentScriptError",
        "message": "The provided script failed with the following error:\r\nMicrosoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultDataServiceClient.SetSecret(String vaultName, String secretName, SecureString secretValue, PSKeyVaultSecretAttributes secretAttributes)\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.SetAzureKeyVaultSecret.ExecuteCmdlet()\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.<>c__3`1.<ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob>b__3_0(T c)\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet, Action`1 executor)\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet)\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()\r\nat <ScriptBlock>, /mnt/azscripts/azscriptinput/userscript.ps1: line 46\r\nat <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1\r\nat <ScriptBlock>, /mnt/azscripts/azscriptinput/DeploymentScript.ps1: line 264. Please refer to https://aka.ms/DeploymentScriptsTroubleshoot for more deployment script information."
      }
    ]
  }
} (Code:Conflict)
CorrelationId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

A Vnet with some subnets used for app services were configured so that those app services can have access to key vault secrets.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Any workaround? Maybe a command that we can run that allows us to connect to the vnet?

Answer (score 1):

A work-around could be to change the VNET settings on the vault, then run the script, and then re-set the VNET settings to its original state. It kinda sucks but it is the only thing I got working for me when handling this situation (though in my case It was a Powershell script).

Or, you could run the script on a VM, that is in a authorised subnet.

Comment: Hi @JarroVGIT, thanks for the ideas, yes i agree reseting the access option for keyvault sucks and i'm not willing to do anything like that in the system and client i'm working on. The second option seems like a great idea, but having a dedicated VM inside the VNET to run the script seems like a waste of resources and money, maybe creating a container instance and connecting to the VNET is something that could be possible but i'm already seeing lots of work doing all of that. If i don't find anything easier than that i guess i'll keep this as a manual step. Thanks.